# how can I fix this Towers of Hanoi program for my desired output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

```
def moveTower(height,fromPole, toPole, withPole):
    if height >= 1:
        moveTower(height-1,fromPole,withPole,toPole)
        moveDisk(fromPole,toPole)
        moveTower(height-1,withPole,toPole,fromPole)

def moveDisk(fp,tp):
    print("("+fp + "," +tp+')')


moveTower(4,"A","B","C")
```

I need the output to be a list of tuples (ex: `[('A','C'),('A','B'), ...]`)

Current output:

```
(A,C)
(A,B)
(C,B)
(A,C)
(B,A)
(B,C)
(A,C)
(A,B)
(C,B)
(C,A)
(B,A)
(C,B)
(A,C)
(A,B)
(C,B)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should *not* print the elements. Probably the most elegant is here to construct a *generator*:

```
def moveTower(height,fromPole, toPole, withPole):
    if height >= 1:
        yield from moveTower(height-1,fromPole,withPole,toPole)
        yield (fromPole, toPole)
        yield from moveTower(height-1,withPole,toPole,fromPole)
```

`yield <expr>` here thus emits the value that is constructed by the `<expr>` in a generator, and `yield from <iterable>` is used to emit all elements from the `<iterable>` as elements of this generator.

We can then use `list(..)` to materialize the generator:

```
>>> list(moveTower(2, *'ABC'))
[('A', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'B')]
>>> list(moveTower(3, *'ABC'))
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('A', 'B')]
>>> list(moveTower(4, *'ABC'))
[('A', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'B'), ('C', 'A'), ('B', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'B')]
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest modification to your code would be to append them to a list:

```
result = []

def moveTower(height,fromPole, toPole, withPole):
    if height >= 1:
        moveTower(height-1,fromPole,withPole,toPole)
        moveDisk(fromPole,toPole)
        moveTower(height-1,withPole,toPole,fromPole)

def moveDisk(fp,tp):
    result.append((fp,tp))

moveTower(4,"A","B","C")
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('A', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'B'), ('C', 'A'), ('B', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'B')]
```